# Poisson equation with a source term that is a full divergence

Tags: poissons-equation

Can the Poisson equation be solved exactly when we know that the source term is a divergence?

$\nabla^2 \psi = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{F}$

Comment: In how many dimensions? In what domain? Are there boundary conditions?

Answer (score 1):

If $F$ is a [conservative vector field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_vector_field), there exists $\phi$ such that $\nabla\phi=F$. Even if $F$ is not conservative we can in many cases decompose it into $F=\nabla\phi+v$ where $\nabla\cdot v=0$ by [Helmholtz's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition). Then $\phi$ is a "particular solution," to borrow a term from O.D.E.'s. If $\mu$ is a solution to Laplace's equation, $\psi=\phi+\mu$ is a solution to $$\nabla^2 \psi=\nabla\cdot F.$$

Comment: @user250673 There are versions of Hodge/Helmholtz  decomposition with boundary conditions, too. Look them up.

Comment: Ok, all these approaches just express the same thing in different terms, and there appears to be no easy way to solve the Poisson equation.

Comment: Do you know what $F$ is?

Comment: I was able to write it as $\mathbf{F}=(\nabla u \cdot \nabla u) \nabla u$ where we also know $\nabla^2 u = 0$.

Comment: If that is the case $$\nabla\cdot F=\nabla\cdot\left[(\nabla u\cdot\nabla u)\nabla u\right]\\=\nabla(\nabla u\cdot\nabla u)\cdot\nabla u+(\nabla u\cdot\nabla u)\nabla^2u\\=(2\nabla u\nabla^2u)\cdot\nabla u\\=0,$$ and you are left with Laplace's equation which is probably either very good for you, or very bad for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I believe $\nabla (\nabla u \cdot \nabla u) = 2 (\nabla u \cdot \nabla)\nabla u$ and that is not zero.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I'm misremembering my vector identities.